# LINQ to get the field values seperated by delimiter

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, join, self, delimiter

I have a situation where I need to display **ItemID** and ItemName from **Items** table. Let's say **ItemID** is 002, and **ItemName** is Apple. I have another field called **SupplementaryItems** in the table which stores related **ItemID** seperated by | (delimiter), something like **003|004|005**. I am using MVC3 with a repository pattern, something like

```
var items = _dataContext.items.AsQueryable();
items = from i in items 
          where i.Item_ID.equals(itemId)
           select i;
```

The above query with an itemId 002 will return Apple which works fine. Now, I also need to display all the supplementaryItems with their corresponding ItemName which means I need to split the supplementaryItem into array and use something like supplementaryItemArray contains itemID. But in this case, I need two separate calls to database, first one will return only item with itemID where I store the supplementaryItemID in a variable.

```
 var supplementMaterialsArr = supplementMaterials.ToString().Split('|');
```

and second one will return all the items, and I will loop through the second one to get the ItemName from the ItemID. FYI, this approach requires two separate calls to be made from controller, something like

```
var itemInformationAll = _repository.GetAllItems();
var itemInformation = _repository.GetItemDetailInformation(id);
```

I think this is not so efficient approach. Anybody has better solution to this? Should I use LINQ self join? But if I use self join, will I able to get the supplemetaryItem with their corresponding ItemName with a single query?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you didn't create another table to store the supplementary items in rather than cramming them into a single field?  It would make things much easier for you.

Comment: Creating database is not in my hand. Database admin did it, and I am left to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with. It will result in two queries, but never pulls the entire table into memory.

```
var q = from item in
        (from item in TblItems
        where item.ItemID == 1
        select new
        {
            Name = item.ItemName,
            SupplementaryItems = item.SupplementaryItems.Split('|')
        }).AsEnumerable()
        select new
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            SupplementaryItems = TblItems.Where (x => 
                item.SupplementaryItems.Select(y => int.Parse(y))
                .Contains(x.ItemID))
        };
```

I would however recommend to change the DB structure ta have a seperate table for the referencing items.

Comment: Looking at the generated SQL, [String.Split] is done outside of the SQL statement, so it appears that two queries is the only option unless you write a stored procedure. Ultimately a separate table would be much easier as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your approach. @MiG - Yeah with two separate queries, I got this working. But, I am concerned with the efficiency here. So, I am also thinking of alternative solution. The current solution looks like this `var items = _dataContext.items.AsQueryable();`                                   `var suppItems = from i in items where i.Item_ID.Equals(itemId) select i.Supp_Items;` Then split suppItems into array `var tempSup = suppItems.Split('|');`  Then call another query `query2 = from i in items where tempSup.Contains(i.Item_ID) select i;`